# Python: How to pass numpy array to matlab array efficiently

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am working on a project in python. Due to some reason, I have to call matlab for calculation

ubuntu 14.04 64bit

python 2.7.6

numpy 1.11.1

matlab 2016a linux-64bit

```
import matlab
import matlab.engine
import numpy as np
import time

data = np.random.rand(1000, 100, 100)

print ('pass begin')
st = time.time()
data_matlab = matlab.double(data.tolist())
print ('pass numpy to matlab finished in {:.2f} sec'.format(time.time() - st))
```

passing a float64 type numpy array with shape of 1000,100,100 to matlab array takes 63.49 seconds. This is unacceptable. Is there any efficient way to passing big data array from numpy to matlab array in python ?

```
pass begin
pass numpy to matlab finished in 63.49 sec
```

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure. Because if I pass a numpy random array with shape (1, 100, 100) to matlab array only takes 0.03 sec. Therefore, creating matlab array in python does not start the matlab engine automatically.

Comment: `.tolist()` will not consume much time. The time is being consumed by `matlab.double`. If you are passing `float32`, why are you using `double`? Try `single` if available, maybe that will be faster. Last option is to split your array, convert them in parallel, and stitch them up somehow... But honestly, you are converting 77 MB of data there, maybe you could cut it some slack... (Or use Python end to end, if possible.)

Comment: `tolist`is going to be pretty expensive here, since that will "box" every float in the array into a python float

Comment: Does that time measurement include time taken in executing MATLAB itself? (e.g., boot up time)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with MATLAB R2022a, this operation is at least an order of magnitude faster than in previous releases. When I run the code sample above on a Windows 10 machine, the operation takes consistently less than 2 seconds now as opposed to the more than 63 seconds reported in the original question. See [release notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html) under "Performance"/"MATLAB Engine API for Python: Improved performance with large multidimensional arrays in Python".